# How to get statusbar height in Android XML layout?

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I have two same screens, with a logo at the center of the screen.

However, one screen has statusbar height considered while the other one doesn't, so the position of the logo does not match between the two.

This is the code on xml.

screen 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item
        android:height="200dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

screen 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "39dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I use galaxy s10, which has height of statusbar of 39dp. 
Now I can manually set margin of 39 to match the position of the logo(like the code above), but that is only for one specific device(which is s10). I need to set the margin dynamically for different mobile devices.

How do I do this? and why does one screen integrates the status bar height while the other doesn't?

P.s. This is a react-native project.

Comment: oh sorry I'm mistake This method is used in java file.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm looking for the same.